# Do a diver and a clownfish share a 10 year friendship?

Tags: zoology

A YouTube video from The Dodo, called *[Clownfish Named Nemo Has 10-Year Friendship with This Diver](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0x4LX_6P9No&feature=youtu.be)* shows footage of a New Caledonian scuba diver, Marino, who claims to have a special relationship with a clownfish, who will come out of the reef when summoned, and interact with the diver.

[Fishlore](https://www.fishlore.com/Profiles-ClownFish.htm) explains clownfish usually don't live this long - but it is possible.

> Lifespan : 3 - 6 years generally, but see comment below from Dudley who has a pair of percula clowns that has been alive for 27 years!

They also say that tank-raised clownfish tend to live longer.

Is this story true?

Comment: I removed the question asking whether the clownfish can recognise this particular diver; it is sufficient that the clownfish does not try to escape when in the presence of a diver. Perhaps it will play/interact with any diver? Perhaps all clownfish will play/interact with any diver.